# How does MEAN js handle the Authentication?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I want to know the basic flow.

As far as I know, when the signin API is called, `passport.js` creates the session and stores it in mongo.

Who creates the session? Who creates the cookie? Express or Passport?

I read that when other requests come, user object is attached to it, using the session id. Who does that? Express server or passport.js or someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `express-session()` middleware ExpressJs create cookies and store a session id in user browser.  Access cookie at server side `console.log(req.cookies['connect.sid']);`

[express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) is responsible to create session. Passport use **express-session** to serialize and deserialize user object. When user authenticates itself then user object serialize and store in session. In each request `passport.deserializeUser` middleware deserialize the user and populate into `req.user` object.

[Click here](https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive) for best article of ExpressJs and PassportJs.

Comment: Well written answer, +1 for covering serializing and deserializing user in addition to the asked questions about the session and cookies.